# Error installing ruby packages

Tags: rvm

I used the following command to run the installation

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --autolibs=3 --ruby
```

I then received a error
[image]

I then checked the error, and below is the log,

```
[2013-05-18 12:11:22] requirements_osx_port_libs_install
Error: 
Error: No valid Xcode installation is properly selected.
Error: Please use xcode-select to select an Xcode installation:
Error:     sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer # version 4.6.1
Error: 
Warning: xcodebuild exists but failed to execute
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for apple-gcc42
--->  Dependencies to be installed: cctools ld64 llvm-3.2 gcc_select
--->  Building llvm-3.2
Error: org.macports.build for port llvm-3.2 returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install llvm-3.2
Please see the log file for port llvm-3.2 for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_lang_llvm-3.2/llvm-3.2/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: cctools ld64 llvm-3.2 gcc_select
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port apple-gcc42 failed
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
```

I checked my xcode version (I'm still subscribed to the $99, if that means anything), and it says this

xcode-select version 2003

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of xcode? it is 4.6.2. If you're uaing Mountain Lion, this can be done via the appstore on OSX.

Comment: thanks for that. the line about the xcode has disappeared. How about the LLVM 3.2? I don't know whats wrong there

Comment: LLVM is installed when you install xcode. It is the C and C++ compiler that is required to compile Ruby.

Comment: @Kashyap so what does that mean? should I install some sort of compiler and from where?

Comment: Its packaged with Xcode.

Comment: haha. ok thats not helping. So are you telling me to remove xcode and install again?

Comment: I actually have no problems with the Xcode part. the new log doesn't have the xcode part anymore. It's the LLVM3.2 thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. Thanks for all the comments.

I was installing rvm last night, and my internet connection got cut off. That corrupted the installation. The problem was with Xcode. I uninstalled then install again, and then re install rvm, and it worked.